# Second Order Linear Differential Question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm tutoring a student, and they brought me this question:

Solve the equation $xy'' + y' = 0$.

I don't know the answer, and would love some help.  I know I should know this, but maybe I'm just too tired from school.  Any simple solutions?

Comment: Multiply by $x$ and apply Cauchy-Euler.

Comment: http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt1.pdf See this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve: $xy^{\prime\prime}+y^\prime=0$.

Multiply by $x$ to obtain

$$ x^2y^{\prime\prime}+xy^\prime=0 \tag{1}$$

which makes it a Cauchy-Euler equation which has solutions of the form $y=x^m$.

So let $y=x^m,\,y^\prime=mx^{m-1},\,y^{\prime\prime}=m(m-1)x^{m-2}$ and substitute into equation (1) to obtain

$$m(m-1)x^{m-2}x^2+mx^{m-1}x=0 $$

$$m(m-1)x^m+mx^m=0 $$
$$m^2x^m=0$$

and conclude that $m=0$. So one solution is $y_1=x^0=1$. But $m=0$ is a double solution. For Cauchy-Euler this means to get a second linearly independent solution one multiplies the first solution by $\ln(x)$.

So the general solution is

$$ y=c_1+c_2\ln(x) $$

which is easily verified.

Note that C-E equations can also be solved using the substitution $x=e^t$. Said substitution in this case will result in the DE $\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Two-terms expressions that involve derivatives can often (in educational examples) be a derivative of some simple expression. For example, here $xy'' + y'$ is a $\left ( xy' \right)'$ in disguise. So $$xy'' + y' = 0$$ leads to $$xy' = C_1$$ and finally to $$y = C_1 \ln x + C_2.$$

Answer (score 0):

If this is a homework question, then the intent is probably to treat this as a "dependent variable missing" problem.  Since $y$ doesn't appear in the equation, the trick is to let $v=y'$ so that $v' = y''$.  Then the equation is 1st-order in $v$:

$$xv'+v=0,$$

which we solve in the usual way to get $v=c_1/x$.  Then put $y'$ back in for $v$:

$$y'=\frac{c_1}{x},$$

and again solve in the usual way to get

$$y = c_1\ln x + c_2.$$